# Block argument does not work when reopening viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

This is my code:

```
-(void)playCurrentTrack
{
    [[AFSoundManager sharedManager] startStreamingRemoteAudioFromURL:[[Playlist sharedInstance] currentSong].URLString andBlock:^(int percentage, CGFloat elapsedTime, CGFloat timeRemaining, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {
        if (!error) {
            //some labels changing
        } else {
            NSLog(@"There has been an error playing the remote file: %@", [error description]);
        }
    }];
}
```

When I reopen the viewcontroller that contains it, the code in the block stops being executed.

This is the [AFSound manager library](https://github.com/AlvaroFranco/AFSoundManager) code

```
-(void)startStreamingRemoteAudioFromURL:(NSString *)url andBlock:(progressBlock)block {
    //Some code here
    if (block) {
                block(percentage, CMTimeGetSeconds(_player.currentItem.currentTime), timeRemaining, error, NO);
            }
    //some other code
}
```

Comment: How is the code you posted being called?  When you say "reopen the viewcontroller", what is actually happening in code?

Comment: It is called when I push this VC froom root navigation view controller with some parameters. When I change track inside my VC, labels start updating.